# How do I change the time period which a new message is notified to my application from a gsm modem using SMSlib

Tags: java, gsm, smslib

Here are a few changes I made to the ReadMessages class but it still takes like 30-45 seconds for the a new message notification.

```
Service.getInstance().S.CNMI_EMULATOR_INTERVAL = 2;       Service.getInstance().S.WATCHDOG_INTERVAL = 3;
```

I minimised the period to which the application checks if there is any new message and set it to 2.

Any changes to the code or advise will be appreciated.

Below is the ReadMessages class.

```
package smsapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.smslib.AGateway;
import org.smslib.AGateway.GatewayStatuses;
import org.smslib.AGateway.Protocols;
import org.smslib.ICallNotification;
import org.smslib.IGatewayStatusNotification;
import org.smslib.IInboundMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.IOrphanedMessageNotification;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage.MessageClasses;
import org.smslib.Library;
import org.smslib.Message.MessageTypes;
import org.smslib.Service;
import org.smslib.modem.SerialModemGateway;

public class ReadMessages {

    public static int lastMemoryIndex = 0;

    public void doIt() throws Exception {
        // Define a list which will hold the read messages.
        List<InboundMessage> msgList;
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound & status report
        // messages.
        InboundNotification inboundNotification = new InboundNotification();
        // Create the notification callback method for inbound voice calls.
        CallNotification callNotification = new CallNotification();
        //Create the notification callback method for gateway statuses.
        GatewayStatusNotification statusNotification = new GatewayStatusNotification();
        OrphanedMessageNotification orphanedMessageNotification = new OrphanedMessageNotification();
        try {
            System.out.println("Example: Read messages from a serial gsm modem.");
            System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
            System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
            // Create the Gateway representing the serial GSM modem.
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.COM9", "COM9", 115200, "", "");
            // Set the modem protocol to PDU (alternative is TEXT). PDU is the default, anyway...
            gateway.setProtocol(Protocols.PDU);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Inbound messages?
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            // Do we want the Gateway to be used for Outbound messages?
            gateway.setOutbound(true);
            // Let SMSLib know which is the SIM PIN.
            gateway.setSimPin("4236");
            // Set up the notification methods.
            Service.getInstance().setInboundMessageNotification(inboundNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setCallNotification(callNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setGatewayStatusNotification(statusNotification);
            Service.getInstance().setOrphanedMessageNotification(orphanedMessageNotification);
            // Add the Gateway to the Service object.
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
            // Similarly, you may define as many Gateway objects, representing
            // various GSM modems, add them in the Service object and control all of them.
            // Start! (i.e. connect to all defined Gateways)
            Service.getInstance().startService();
            Service.getInstance().S.CNMI_EMULATOR_INTERVAL = 2;
            Service.getInstance().S.WATCHDOG_INTERVAL = 3;

            // Printout some general information about the modem. 
            System.out.println("CNMI_EMULATOR_INTERVAL " + Service.getInstance().S.CNMI_EMULATOR_INTERVAL);
            System.out.println("WATCHDOG_INTERVAL " + Service.getInstance().S.WATCHDOG_INTERVAL);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Modem Information:");
            System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
            System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
            System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
            System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
            System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
            System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
            System.out.println();
            // In case you work with encrypted messages, its a good time to declare your keys.
            // Create a new AES Key with a known key value. 
            // Register it in KeyManager in order to keep it active. SMSLib will then automatically
            // encrypt / decrypt all messages send to / received from this number.
            //  Service.getInstance().getKeyManager().registerKey("+306948494037", new AESKey(new SecretKeySpec("0011223344556677".getBytes(), "AES")));
            // Read Messages. The reading is done via the Service object and
            // affects all Gateway objects defined. This can also be more directed to a specific
            // Gateway - look the JavaDocs for information on the Service method calls.

            msgList = new ArrayList<InboundMessage>();

            Service.getInstance().readMessages(msgList, MessageClasses.ALL);
            int size = msgList.size();
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                InboundMessage msg = msgList.get(x);
                if (x == (size - 1)) {
                    System.out.println(msg.getMemIndex() + " " + msg.getText());
                }
                lastMemoryIndex = (int) msg.getMemIndex();
            }
//            for (InboundMessage msg : msgList) {
//                System.out.println(msg.getMessageId() +" "+msg.getText());
//            }
            // Sleep now. Emulate real world situation and give a chance to the notifications
            // methods to be called in the event of message or voice call reception.
            System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to stop service.");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
        }
    }

    public class InboundNotification implements IInboundMessageNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, MessageTypes msgType, InboundMessage msg) {
            if (msgType == MessageTypes.INBOUND) {
                String originator = msg.getOriginator();
                // System.out.println(" >>> New Inbound message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
                int newIndex = (int) msg.getMemIndex();
                if (newIndex > lastMemoryIndex) {
                    System.out.println(msg.getDate() + " " + msg.getText());
                    String message = msg.getText();
                    String[] details = dbutils.checker.getLipaDetails(message);
                    String lipa_code = details[0];
                    String lipa_date = details[1];
                    String lipa_time = details[2];
                    String lipa_amount = details[3];
                    String lipa_sys_amount = details[4];
                    String phone_number = details[5];
                    String names = details[6];
                    String received = "no";
                    String cashier = f_SuperMarket.SuperMarketViews.salesPerson.getText();
                    String sysdate = dbutils.formatedDate.getdate();
                    String systime = dbutils.formatedDate.getTime();
                    String date = dbutils.formatedDate.getDateFromDB(sysdate);
                    String time = dbutils.formatedDate.getTimeFromDb(systime);

                    dbutils.updateTables.newLipaNaMpesaEntry(lipa_code, lipa_date, lipa_time, lipa_amount, phone_number,
                            names, sysdate, date, systime, time, received, cashier, message);
//                    try {
//                        Service.getInstance().deleteMessage(msg);
//                    } catch (Exception e) {
//                    }
                    refreshLipaTable();
                    lastMemoryIndex = newIndex;
                }
            } else if (msgType == MessageTypes.STATUSREPORT) {
                System.out.println(">>> New Inbound Status Report message detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void refreshLipaTable() {
        String columns = "LIPA_CODE,LIPA_AMOUNT,LIPA_DATE,LIPA_TIME,NAMES";
        dbutils.updateTables.refreshTable(columns, "lipanampesa", f_SuperMarket.MakePayment.lipaTable);
    }

    public class CallNotification implements ICallNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, String callerId) {
            System.out.println(">>> New call detected from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId() + " : " + callerId);
        }
    }

    public class GatewayStatusNotification implements IGatewayStatusNotification {

        public void process(AGateway gateway, GatewayStatuses oldStatus, GatewayStatuses newStatus) {
            System.out.println(">>> Gateway Status change for " + gateway.getGatewayId() + ", OLD: " + oldStatus + " -> NEW: " + newStatus);
        }
    }

    public class OrphanedMessageNotification implements IOrphanedMessageNotification {

        public boolean process(AGateway gateway, InboundMessage msg) {
            System.out.println(">>> Orphaned message part detected from " + gateway.getGatewayId());
            System.out.println(msg);
            // Since we are just testing, return FALSE and keep the orphaned message part.
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReadMessages app = new ReadMessages();
        try {
            app.doIt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to consider reception speed for notifications from your implementation of the `IInboundMessageNotification`,
don't forget a lot depends on the quality of your physical environment, equipment and QoS of your carrier.

I've also sometimes encountered waiting times up to 20 - 30 seconds with good reception on a high quality carrier.

Have you tried using the SIM from your own cellphone in your USB Dongle and compared reception times?
If your phone has the same reception speed, don't get your hopes up for anything better.

The standard poll interval in the `org.smslib.Settings` class is already defined pretty tight on 200ms.

`public int SERIAL_POLLING_INTERVAL = 200;`

If you still want to mess around with the settings you may consider setting constants before you invoke **`Service.getInstance().startService()`**

`Service.getInstance().S.CNMI_EMULATOR_INTERVAL = 2;
 Service.getInstance().S.WATCHDOG_INTERVAL = 3;`

Also, try to use the setter `setSettings(Settings settings)` for these kind of things, 
I'm using smslib v3.5.4, the `Settings S` variable is private in that version.

If you're messing with the source code, you may not be able to upgrade your code easily to a later version with contains bugfixes.